# Unable to get QuerySet Class Object query to being printed

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, overriding

So for some reason I do not know why, but I am getting

```
>>> song = Song()
>>> song.album = album1
>>> song.file_type = 'mp3'
>>> song.song_title = ' I hate my boyfriend'
>>> song.save()
>>> song.song_title = ' I love my boyfriend'
>>> song.save()
>>> album1.song_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Song: Song object>, <Song: Song object>]>
```

Instead of the names of the songs.

In my code I have an overload str method and it doesn't seem to have worked.
Any idea whats going on

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the **`__repr__`** method for implicit console printing, `__str__` is for formatting and `print` invokes.